# Change Terminator title command

Tags: terminator

How to change temporarily the name of one of the subterminals in Terminator from the command line of that specific subterminal?

I have tried for example this:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"
```

but without success

Comment: Is this your answer what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8850484/4023950

Comment: In Terminator it's possible to change the window title using "CTRL + Alt + W" shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

I just hit the same problem and think its a bug/feature.

I'm using 'terminator 0.97' and for me the following only works if you have not already set a title for your terminator terminal using '--title' or '-T':

```
echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Ubuntu 15.04, using BASH in Terminator. This seems to work for me:

```
$ echo -en "\e]2;YOUR TITLE HERE\a"
```

I made this function for it in ~/.bashrc

```
function title()
{
   echo -en "\e]2;$1\a"
}
```

Use it on the command line like:

```
$ title 'MY NEW TITLE'
```